# CSS - Multiple IDs, only one is working

Tags: html, css

I have two html code snippets:

```css
#header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Gill Sans MT";
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#123 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Gill Sans MT";
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <!-- *** Section 1 *** --->
  <h3>Time series of applications to 'Research Grants (Open Call)' for this Financial Year<br> and the previous three with 'Bollinger Bands'.</h3><br>
</div>

<div id="123">
  <!-- *** Section 1 *** --->
  <h3>Time series of applications to 'Research Grants (Open Call)' for this Financial Year<br> and the previous three with 'Bollinger Bands'.</h3><br>
</div>
```

Exactly the same content, but with different IDs.

Now, only the `header` ID works, the `123` doesnt.... and if I put the `123` css ABOVE the `header` css, none of them work.

Can someone explain what is happening, cos I am stumped!

Comment: ^ [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html) is not a duplicate, numerical ids are valid.

Comment: It is NOT a duplicate. The 123 was just an example. It could be any value, it still does not work.

Comment: I have create a snippet for you, use some other id and try to reproduce the issue

Comment: Please show your actual HTML and CSS. If you show imaginary code, you get solutions for the imaginary problem.

Comment: in the snippet here, numerical id doesn't work, so use another id and it will work

Comment: Hey, I am posting a new question with my FULL code. Hopefully that is more helpful! :)

Answer (score -1):

An id must begin with an alphabet [a-zA-Z]. This explains why 123 is not working.

Try changing id. Also, are you using some other framework like bootstrap?

Comment: I have tried lots of values. Still causing the same issue :/... no bootstrap. I will post question again with FULL html/css. Thank you

Comment: Numerical id are valid in HTML5